# Unable to run carla Spawn_npc python eamples?

Tags: python, numpy, ros, simulator, carla

Hi I have followed the newest [Carla](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/#installation-summary) release following this:
However when I run the spawn_npc example I have the error below:

```
/opt/carla-simulator/PythonAPI/examples$ python3 spawn_npc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spawn_npc.py", line 30, in
from numpy import random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have installed numpy and updated my python version yet still any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have numpy installed, at least not in your python3 environment. Run:

```
pip3 install numpy
```